# display a layer with an openlayers map using spring boot

Tags: java, html, spring-boot, openlayers

i would like to display a layer ( MultiPolygons) , on a openlayers map BUT i don't know how can i do it  with spring boot , if anyone can help me i will be really grateful .

PS : i'm using postrges

i read i little bit about hibernate-spatial but i still don't know how can i do it.

this is how i declared my layer  :

```
package com.example.demo;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;


@Entity
@Table(name="polygon")
public class Couche {
    // pour indiquer la clé primaire 
    @Id
    @Column(name = "gid" )
    //L' @GeneratedValueannotation consiste à configurer le mode d'incrémentation de la colonne
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long  gid  ; 

    @Column(columnDefinition = "geometry(MultiPolygon,4326)")
    private String geom ;


    //geters seters pour gid 
    public Long getGid() {
        return  gid;
    }
    public void setGid(Long  gid) {
        this. gid =  gid;
    }

    //geters seters pour Geom
    public String getGeom() {
        return geom;
    }
    public void setGeom(String geom) {
        this.geom = geom;
    }

}
```

This is my HTML page that contain the map :

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/openlayers/openlayers.github.io@master/en/v6.5.0/css/ol.css" type="text/css">
    <style>
      .map {
        height: 400px;
        width: 100%;
      }
    </style>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/openlayers/openlayers.github.io@master/en/v6.5.0/build/ol.js"></script>
    <title>OpenLayers example</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h2>My Map</h2>

    <div id="map" class="map"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    //////////////////////////////////////////// zoomslider
    var zoomslider = new ol.control.ZoomSlider();
    
    // la carte 
      var map = new ol.Map({
        target: 'map',
        layers: [
          new ol.layer.Tile({
            source: new ol.source.OSM()
          })
        ],
        view: new ol.View({
          center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([37.41, 8.82]),
          zoom: 4
        }),
        controls: ol.control.defaults().extend
      ([new ol.control.FullScreen(),

          zoomslider
         
      ]),

      });


    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is the problem with the posted code?  The HTML displays a map for me.  I don't see any attempt to load data from your "layer", which seems to be an interface to a database.  How do you retrieve the data from the database?  What does the Multipolygon data you retrieve/have stored look like?

Comment: @geocodezip   there is no prob with the code , i juste don't know how to continue and  display a layer ( with 2 polygones ) on a openlayers map ,

Comment: how can i do it by using spring boot  , that's my question , how can i passe the layer (that i have in postgres ) from the backend to the frontend